# Cypress shows 401 Unauthorized when visiting page

Tags: javascript

I am using Cypress to test some web applications.
Most page addresses behave completely identical to when I visit them manually.

However, I have some pages that return a 401 - Unauthorized as soon as I visit them through Cypress.
These problematic pages are simple login pages with username password, and the error is thrown before I even start filling username/password fields.

I have already switched between the Chrome and Electron browsers, but had no luck so far.

Does anyone have any idea what I could try to overcome this 401 problem?
I can't find anything useful on google on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. It's related to a `POST` request being made between visits which requires auth. Cypress unauthorizes SOMETIMES between tests, which is flaky behavior I don't think is intended (there's a report on this but not with as much info as they need, I'll add more info to the GitHub thread ASAP).

For now, to solve the issue, I added a `cy.wait()` before each visit in the test, (especially of the one that was failing). It made even the page giving me the `401` error, pass. A simple example is provided below:

```js
it('checks the xxx page', () => {
  cy.wait(20000)
  cy.visit('/page')
})

it('verifies xxx page is loaded', () => {
  cy.wait(10000)
  cy.get('element').should('contain', 'Header text')
})
```

You can also do a (not so recommended) workaround by putting the visits in the same test:

```js
it('checks the xxx page', () => {
  cy.wait(20000)
  cy.visit('/page')

  cy.wait(10000)
  cy.get('element').should('contain', 'Header text')
  cy.visit('/anotherpage')
...
})
```